# If $V=\overline V$ where $V$ is a vector space, then there exists a real basis of $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Considering $V$ to be a vector space over $\mathbb C$ then if $V=\overline V$ how can i assure there is a real basis?

My first consideration was that if $w \in V$ then $\bar w \in V$ so $Re(w) \in V$ but i can't construct a basis over this fact.

Given a basis i know that its conjugated is also a basis, is the sum of elements of a basis also a basis?

Comment: When you say $V=\bar{V}$, what do you mean?

Comment: What *is* $\overline V$?

Comment: Considering $B$ a vectorial space over $\mathbb R$ we define its complexification a space over $\mathbb C$, also given a subspace of $B$ complexificated, we have that the space $= \overline V = \overline {ger{S}} = ger{\overline S} $

Comment: what is $ger$? What is $S$?

Comment: I guess "real basis" means a $\mathbb C$ basis consisting of vectors whose entries are all from $\mathbb R$??  Because it is trivial that there is an $\mathbb R$ basis.

Comment: $S$ is a subset of the vector field, in this case a subset of elements that is a basis, ger means it is generated, usual notation in my country not sure what is common here

Comment: yes, i guess @rschwieb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say $V=\overline{V}$, I'll assume that what you mean is there exists an additive involution of $V$, $v\mapsto \bar{v}$, such that $\overline{zv} = \bar{z}\bar{v}$. The real subspace is then the subset $W=\renewcommand\Re{\operatorname{Re}}\Re(V)=\{v\in V: v=\bar{v}\}$.

We want to construct a complex basis of $V$ which lies in $W$.

Observe that as real vector spaces $V=W\oplus iW$, since for any $v\in V$,
$$v = \frac{v+\bar{v}}{2} + i \frac{v-\bar{v}}{2i},$$
and $W\cap iW=0$.

Then choose a real basis for $W$, $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. I claim $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ is a $\Bbb{C}$ basis for $V$.

To see this, simply observe that $\dim_{\Bbb{R}} W = \frac{1}{2}\dim_{\Bbb{R}} V = \dim_{\Bbb{C}}V$, since $V=W\oplus iW$, and $v_1,\ldots,v_n,iv_1,\ldots,iv_n$ span $V$ as an $\Bbb{R}$ vector space. Therefore $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ span $V$ as a $\Bbb{C}$ vector space, and they must form a basis, since there are the correct number of vectors.

**Special case**

In the particular case where we start with a real vector space $W$, and define $V=W\otimes_{\Bbb{R}} \Bbb{C}$, the involution on $V$ is induced by complex conjugation on $\Bbb{C}$, and the real subspace can naturally be identified with $W$ via the map $w\mapsto w\otimes 1$.

In the even more particular case where $W=\Bbb{R}^n$, $V=\Bbb{C}^n$, the involution on $V$ induced by complex conjugation is exactly what you'd expect, namely the conjugate of a column vector
$$\begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \\ \vdots\\z_n\end{pmatrix}\text{ is }\begin{pmatrix} \bar{z_1} \\ \bar{z_2} \\ \vdots\\\bar{z_n}\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: sorry, i now see my writing is confusing, i want a basis over $\mathbb C$ with real vectors only

Comment: @DanielMoraes The part that confuses me about your comment is that I'm pretty sure that that was what my answer addressed. What do you mean when you say a real vector? I defined a real vector to be one such that $v=\bar{v}$.

Comment: when you use $iv_{k}$ you are taking complex vectors

Comment: sorry misread, you are right

Comment: This seems like something that would have a nice category-theoretic explanation.

Comment: @R.Burton It does feel like that doesn't it? I'm not quite sure how the category theory would work, but this should generalize to the following statement, which might make something categorical more clear. Suppose $G$ acts on a field $K$ and a vector space $V$ over $K$ such that $(cv)^g = c^g v^g$, then $V$ has a $G$-invariant $K$-basis. In other words, there is a $G$-equivariant isomorphism to $K^n$ (with the obvious $G$-action).

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that $\bar{V}=\{\bar{v}\in\mathbb{C}\mid v\in V\}$.

In which case, by definition...

$$V=\mathbb{R}\otimes B$$

Where $B\subset\mathbb{C}$ is your basis.

For each $z\in B$, there are real numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $z=a+bi$. Then, again by definition $\bar{z}=a-bi$. It is trivial to show that $\mathbb{R}=\bar{\mathbb{R}}$, so...

$$V=\bar{V}\iff B=\bar{B}$$

Which implies...

$$\forall a+bi\in B.a+bi=a-bi\implies b=0$$

In other words, the imaginary part of your basis is always $0$.